# Ionic 3 cordova button clicking error

Tags: html, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

When i click on first div it gives me an error

> cannot read property "style" of null

why is this error is occurring? when i use grid it worked fine but when i used div it is giving me error

here is my html

```
<ion-header>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
 maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 <!-- jQuery library -->
 <script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>

 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript --> 
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>


 </ion-header>




 <ion-content class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="number">
         9
     </div>

    <div class="center">
  <img src="assets/imgs/wajid.jpg" style="width: 84%;">

 </div>

  <div class="col-xl-12" >



  <div class = "line1" style="width: 18%;" (click)="p10_1()">
  <div class = "sections">نَ</div><!--
 --><div class = "sections">ذِ</div><!--
 --><div class = "sections">اَ</div>


 </div>
```

here is my .ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NativeAudio } from '@ionic-native/native-audio';


@Component({
   selector: 'page-home',
   templateUrl: 'home.html'

 })
 export class HomePage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { 

   }


    p10_1()
   {
        document.getElementById("sec1").style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById("sec2").style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById("sec3").style.color = "red"
        var bleep = new Audio();
        bleep.src = './assets/sounds/q1p10_1.mp3';
        bleep.play();
        bleep.onended = function() {
        document.getElementById("sec1").style.color = "black";
        document.getElementById("sec2").style.color = "black";
        document.getElementById("sec3").style.color = "black";
       }
      }
```

Comment: Uhm yeah.. You're calling for elements with id's `sec1`, `sec2`, and `sec3` but according to your posted html file, they dont exist

Comment: And the `<ion-header>` tag isn't equal to the html `<head>` tag, it's a Component for the header (navigation & title bar) of your application

Answer (score 0):

There is id missing in your html.
hence it is not connecting to your .ts file.

```
 <div class="col-xl-12" >
  <div class = "line1" style="width: 18%;" (click)="p10_1()">
  <div id="sec1" class = "sections">نَ</div>
  <div id="sec2" class = "sections">ذِ</div>
  <div id="sec3" class = "sections">اَ</div>
 </div>
```